Using a ShareLink with a custom exported type identifier does not display any sharing options
I'm working with a custom exported type in my macOS app when I found that SwiftUI's ShareLink would not display any options for sharing.
Currently, I have a type that conforms to public.data and public.json, with a unique identifier and file extension too.
Here's a screenshot of the empty share sheet:
:
After searching through the documentation on Uniform Type Identifiers, I found this written about the content type:

For document types, conform to public.content, either directly or by conforming to a type that already conforms to public.content. This conformance allows users to share your type over AirDrop.

This seems to be not true in my context, so I assume that I have made a mistake.
Here's my current Transferable conformance:
extension Quote: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .quote)
    }
}

extension UTType {
    // Real type identifier is not com.example, of course
    static var quote: UTType { UTType(exportedAs: "com.example.quote") }
}

These are the declarations of exported type identifiers and document types in my Xcode project settings:
.
This is what the ShareLink looks like:
ShareLink(
    item: Quote(text: "In a galaxy far far away..."),
    preview: SharePreview("An intersting quote"),
    label: { Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up") }
)

Does anyone know why this issue of having no Share Options is occurring with this custom exported type identifier?
